# PHP: two object array on the loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

In my site I have a section for changing my site's members email.

The request for the members email changes comes as an array with this form:

```
$arrayRequestChangeMembersEmail
: array = 
  0: object(Request) = 
    id: string = 901C6B44-95FC-4281-BB28-4D6B153914C5
    newValue: string = someEmailForId_4C5@email.com
  1: object(Request) = 
    id: string = A5068622-4A6D-4490-A93F-7140F57B24EC
    newValue: string = someEmailForId_4EC@yahoo.es
```

And this is the array of active members who can change their email:

```
$arrayActiveMembersEmail
: array = 
  0: object(Member) = 
    id: string = 901C6B44-95FC-4281-BB28-4D6B153914C5
    activeEmail: string = NULL
  1: object(Member) = 
    id: string = A5068622-4A6D-4490-A93F-7140F57B24EC
    activeEmail: undefined = NULL
```

I need to loop `$arrayActiveMembersEmail` and if the ids are equal to the ids in `$arrayRequestChangeMembersEmail` I need to set the email in newValue to activeEmail in `$arrayActiveMembersEmail`.

How can I do that? I'm totally stuck

I've tried:

```
foreach($arrayRequestChangeMembersEmail as $a1)
{
 foreach($arrayActiveMembersEmail as $a2)
 {
  if($a1->getId() == $a2->getId());
  {   
   //use the setter to set email
  }
 }
}
```

But this is not working because this

```
if($a1->getId() == $a2->getId())
```

can be false but the execution of the program goes on and always steps into the if setting the email :(

Thanks!

Comment: `But this is not working because this ... can be false `  of course it will be. Describe more what you want. Foreach loop you show do it's job search `$a1->getId() == $a2->getId()`, describe more about your logic.

Comment: If you want stop loop on found you should use break command. Read more here http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try whith 2 foreachs

```
foreach $arrayActiveMembersEmail as $active {

 foreach $arrayRequestChangeMembersEmail as $change{

     if ($active['id']==$change['id']){

         $arrayActiveMembersEmail['id'] = $arrayRequestChangeMembersEmail['id']
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: He has object so I think it will be something like `$arrayActiveMembersEmail->id` ...

Comment: didn't notice that, my bad